# Python - Result of ast.literal_eval() is not in order

Tags: python, python-2.7

Order of my dictionary is changed when using ast.literal_eval() function.
Following is my program,

```
dicty="{'@#$':'Please enter a valid Email Address.','testuser1009131@,$%^*&@!$)(:;gmail.com':'Please enter a valid Email Address.','am@am.pm':'None'}"
dictionary=ast.literal_eval(dicty)
print dictionary
```

My Output:

```
{'testuser1009131@,$%^*&@!$)(:;gmail.com': 'Please enter a valid Email Address.', 'am@am.pm': 'None', '@#$': 'Please enter a valid Email Address.'}
```

Expected Output:

```
{'@#$':'Please enter a valid Email Address.','testuser1009131@,$%^*&@!$)(:;gmail.com':'Please enter a valid Email Address.','am@am.pm':'None'}
```

Comment: python dictionaries are not ordered ... Unfortunately, to  get this in order, you'd need to write your own parser or convert the input format to `json` where you can parse via `json.loads` and supply `object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict`...

Comment: Dicts only represent "does this key have a value associated" and "if so, what value?". They do not represent any sort of ordering of the key-value associations they store.

Comment: Confirmed this behavior in Python2.7, but this python version will be depreciated very soon. And, I tested on Python3.6, the order of your input is reserved.